# Make SQLite Window Aggregation function run exactly ONCE over entire table

Tags: sqlite

What SQL query would satisfy all these requirements? I need it to implement and test a window aggregate function.

- The agg function must be called as a **windowing** aggregation function.
- The result must be a single row with a single value in it.
- The agg function must only be called ONCE by SQLite (i.e. one sequence)

For this example, the expected result is: `'aaa,bbb,ccc'`. These are my attempts, none of which satisfy the above.

```sql
-- preload data
CREATE TABLE tbl(a INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, b TEXT);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1, 'bbb'), (2, 'ccc'), (3, 'aaa');


-- This calls window agg function multiple times
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(b)
  OVER (ORDER BY b ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM tbl;
> aaa,bbb,ccc
> aaa,bbb,ccc
> aaa,bbb,ccc


-- This is NOT a window agg func call
-- The order appears correct, but is NOT defined per SQLite docs,
--   and can change in the future
SELECT group_concat(b) FROM (SELECT b FROM tbl ORDER BY b);
> aaa,bbb,ccc


-- This is NOT a window agg func call, and the result is wrong
SELECT group_concat(b) FROM tbl ORDER BY b;
> bbb,ccc,aaa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reliable way to do aggregation with the well defined order is to simply limit result to 1:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(b)
  OVER (ORDER BY b ROWS
        BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM tbl
LIMIT 1;
```

Moreover, the above can be used as a subquery, e.g. if one wants to get a value even if the table is empty:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(
  (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(b)
    OVER (ORDER BY b ROWS
          BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
    FROM tbl
    LIMIT 1
  ),
  'the table is empty'
);
```